# asp.net mvc - dont work background url

Tags: url, background

```
 <%: Html.ActionLink(" ", "Index", "Card", new { hidefocus = "hidefocus" }, new { style = "background: url('Content/shopping_trolley.png') no-repeat center; display:block; height:50px;width:50px;" })%>
```

Views in one folder - but the home and card are displayed, and the others do not - can you help me?

How I can insert this 
`<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl(~/Content/shopping_trolley.png)%>`
into url?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif"/></a>
```

check below example to see

http://gregory.pakosz.fr/stackoverflow/1921726.html

Comment: I need render my action index in controller Card in all my pages! it's dont works!

Comment: my problem is - insert into url this code?

    new { style = "background: url(' 
 <%= Page.ResolveClientUrl(~/Content/shopping_trolley.png)%>   ')